# wordpress chmod(): & file_put_contents & touch(): errors

Tags: php, wordpress, chmod

i am facing the following errors in my website. I have read the other answers on StackOverFlow but didnt find one for me working...

```
Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /home4/gorgeous/public_html/www.glamournation.com.au/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 502

Warning: file_put_contents(/home4/gorgeous/public_html/www.glamournation.com.au/wp-includes/../.htaccess): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home4/gorgeous/public_html/www.glamournation.com.au/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 503

Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /home4/gorgeous/public_html/www.glamournation.com.au/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 504

Warning: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted in /home4/gorgeous/public_html/www.glamournation.com.au/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 508
```

i have used avada theme shared on WP LOcker and plugins are Fusion Builder , revolution Slider, Contact form 7 and All in one WP security.. 
Help me in this matter to get resolved.

Comment: Looks like your WordPress is hacked? Nav_menu.php file seems like to have malicous code which is trying to do malicious stuff which your server is blocking due to restrict permissions . I suggest you install this plugin and scan for any core files changed https://wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/

Comment: more info here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/nav-menuphp-hacked

Comment: Check by inactive the plugins one by one , if this not help change your theme to default twenty sixteen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely looks like the case of WordPress core files being changed as the line numbers mentioned in the file of WP and also the actions it is trying to do are not WordPress related. Your site is hacked, you should repair it and get rid of the malicious code on that file, by replacing core files of WP.

Sorry to be bad news carrier, but I suggest you give this page a read to get your site back:
https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

More information:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/nav-menuphp-hacked

Plugin for scanning and replacing/recovering original core wp files:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/

Comment: Mohsin Bhai... i have installed new wordpress and all new plugins... but issue is same... everything is new and fresh... and site is not published  or famous ... no trafic is there yet...

Comment: @HashirAnwaar could it be that your hosting server is hacked, so the moment your installed WP, the same malicious file somewhere on your server get called/run and impacted the WP again? I suggest you ask your host to run virus scan on your hosting account and see if there are any malicious files there which should not be there at the first place. Then you can take those files down and then do fresh install.